# how to declare behaviors method globally in yii2

Tags: yii2, rate-limiting

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['rateLimiter'] = [
        // Use class
        'class' => RateLimiter::className(),

        'rateLimit' => 5,
        'timePeriod' => 10,

        'separateRates' => false,
        'enableRateLimitHeaders' => false,
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

I need to use rate limiter in my all controller anyway to declare this method globally.

Comment: If [this](https://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/76346-how-to-attach-behavior-to-parent-controller/) doesn't help will post an detailed answer

Comment: yes, its working thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer from [yii documents](https://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/76346-how-to-attach-behavior-to-parent-controller/) and its working for me.